# What is exactly the d__Xa part in stack in async code?

Tags: windows-runtime, stack, async-await

When I have this row in a stack of an exception:

```
WebApiAccessService.<GetStudentKey>d__14a.MoveNext()
```

What is the "d__14a"? Is it something which could tell me (without symbols) some offset from the start of the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace with the weird name tells you that the exception was thrown in the `MoveNext()` method of the `<GetStudentKey>d__14a` type.

When you are using async and await [the compiler generates some code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28944276/98607) to implement a state machine. This state machine involves a struct and in your case the name of the struct is `<GetStudentKey>d__14a`. Obviously, this is not a legal name for a struct in C# even though it works fine in IL but that is exactly why the compiler uses a name that is guaranteed to not conflict with any name you can create yourself.

You will have to look at the [compiler source code](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/) to understand how the `d__14a` part is generated. Most likely the logic is in the method [`MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs,a69eee78fffef6bc) in the `GeneratedNames` class but the exact nature of algorithm should not be important.

The compiler will create similar "invalid" names for auto properties, lambda expressions, anonymous types, iterator blocks etc.