# C# Exceptions In ContinueWith With Class Extension

Tags: c#, continuewith

I created a class extension for manage the exceptions with ContinueWith.

```
public static class ClassExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> ValidateInnerException<T>(this Task<T> task) => task.Exception != null ? throw task.Exception.InnerException ?? task.Exception : task;
}
```

There are two possible implementations using this class extension. The difference is the position of the ValidateInnerException call.

```
public Task<Response> ValidateCall(long periodId)
{
   return _client.Validate(periodId)
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
       return t.ValidateInnerException().Result.Adapt<Response>();
    });
}
```

And

```
public Task<Response> ValidateCall(long periodId)
{
   return _client.Validate(periodId)
    .ValidateInnerException()
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        return t.Result.Adapt<Response>();
    });
}
```

The two implementations pass the Unit Test related with throw exception

```
[Fact]
public async Task Validate_Throw_Exception()
{
    _ = _client
       .Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<long>()))
       .ThrowsAsync(new Exception("Exception"));

    _ = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => _manager.ValidateCall(1));
}
```

The first implementation has a problem, the Sonar marks it as an Code Smell.
[image]

My questions are:

- What is the difference with this two implementations?
- Why Sonar marks the first implementation it as an Code Smell?

Thanks,

Comment: @Fildor But the two implementations have the t.Result, the two implementations have different behaviours?

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood the question.. So, you are wondering why _only_ the first version is considered a problem _and the second is not_?

Comment: While your usage of Result in ContinueWith is correct, it is quite possible that Sonar is unable to determine that ValidateInnerException returns the same Task that was passed in and that calling .Result will not block.

That being said, there are several issues with your implementation. Primarily, it allows the second case which is not correct - Task.Exception may not be set at that point. You probably observe it set as the implementation you tested with is synchronous. Try injecting `await Task.Delay(1000)` and then throw.

Comment: You shouldn't call `ValidateInnerException` before `ContinueWith`, because at that point the `Task` is likely incomplete.

Comment: And for what it's worth, there is no problem accessing `Result` inside `ContinueWith`, because the task will be complete.

Comment: The real answer here is to not use `ContinueWith`.  You should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` in almost all situations, as it makes it much easier and much less error prone to add continuations while properly handling exceptions.

Comment: @Servy _"The real answer here is to not use ContinueWith"_ - while I agree, it would be the better approach, the _question_ is about the behavior of Sonar ... though I would prefer an answer that includes your suggestion over one that doesn't.

Comment: @Fildor And you should not care about how sonar behaves when you do things you already know you shouldn't be doing for other reasons.  That it manages to point out some of the pitfalls of using `ContinueWith` is nice and all, but rather than trying to study all of them in order to be able to write asynchronous code without using `async`, it's far more productive to just *use `async`*.

Comment: _I_ would, yes. Perfectly fair @Servy. Yet I also am experienced enough to know, that in some codebases you are thrown into, there are bad practices already in place and you cannot just snap your fingers and make them go away. Don't get me wrong: I totally agree with your point "use await over ContinueWith". And I also am of the "don't code to please a tool" kind. But: I get that the question is more about understanding what the tool does (and why) in one case which it does not in another.

Comment: The question _I_ would have indeed: Why did Sonar _not_ complain about the use of ContinueWith? :D

Comment: @Fildor with the change of t2, the Sonar marks the same issue, Replace this use of 'Task.Result' with 'await'.

Comment: @Servy I understand the point of "code more maintainable" with async/await, but I'm confussed in terms of performace, the performace is the same? Or the answer is "the overhead is quite small and is usually negligible compared to the resources saved by using async-await"? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944276/will-every-await-operator-result-in-a-state-machine

Comment: @EduardoIsaacBallesteros Performance is irrelevant when the code doesn't work correctly. You wrote buggy code by trying to use `ContinueWIth`.  There are a lot of traps you can easily fall into when using it.  It's *very hard* to use correctly.  The fact that it seems simple makes it all the more insidious, as bugs with it are often in exceptional cases not the standard case, and so are often missed in simple testing.  `await` is much easier to use, and code written with it is much more likely to be correct as a result.

Comment: As far as the actual performance differences, in almost all situations, it's *identical*.  In *some* situations using `async` can have a *very small* additional overhead, when you don't actually need the features it provides.  When you *are* using those features though then it's not an *additional* overhead, it's overhead you also have in the non-`async` version too, because it's necessary for the correctness of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Here Sonar knows 100% that `t` is a completed `Task`, and there is no issue accessing `Result` on a completed `Task`:

```
return _client.Validate(periodId)
    .ValidateInnerException()
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        return t.Result.Adapt<Response>();
    });
```

That's because `ContinueWith` is only invoked on completion.

In this example, Sonar is not so sure, because `ValidateInnerException` is a `Task`-returning method, and that `Task` is not necessarily complete:

```
public Task<Response> ValidateCall(long periodId)
{
   return _client.Validate(periodId)
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
       return t.ValidateInnerException().Result.Adapt<Response>();
    });
}
```

That would be a code-smell, because it's potentially blocking.

Whilst in practice calling `ValidateInnerException()` here will always return a complete `Task` (if no exception is thrown) the tool clearly isn't able to determine that.